# Basic SIP system

Tags: sip

I have been tasked to create a simple local SIP system. We have two Snom 710 phones and we just want one to call the other. We have tried Freeswitch and 3CX. It seems that we are missing something.

In terms of hardware and software, what else do we need other than 2 Snom phones and a Windows 7 laptop or Windows 2k8 Server (no AD or anything, just the OS)?

Also, if the setup is in just local test environment, do I need an SIP Provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Snom phones are *SIP clients* and Freeswitch or 3CX are *SIP Servers*. That's all you need for a local test environment.

I haven't used Freeswitch or 3CX, because I work installing Asterisk that is Linux based. However I can give you general guidelines to achieve a working scenario:

1. Install the server (*Freeswitch* or *3CX*).
2. Check in the configuration of the server that SIP is enabled and which port is using (usually 5060).
3. Verify that the Windows firewall isn't blocking the SIP port.
4. Create on the server two extensions (one for each client) and if the server requires a dialplan (a list of routes that let the server route the calls to the destination), you need to create it.
5. The basic parameters of a extension are username (in some cases it could be the same as the extension number) and password, but there are more parameters. My recommendatio is to use the default parameters provided by the server.
6. On each Snom phone configure the username and password, the IP of the server and the SIP port.
7. Connect the phones to the network and check on the server logs that the login process was correct, sometimes the user needs to be in the form:*user@server*.
8. When the clients have succesfully logged in, try to make a call. Calls use RTP, and depending of the configuration of the server, the RTP connection can go directly from phone to phone or through the server. In the latter case you have to check that the Windows firewall isn't blocking the RTP packets.
9. If the call can't be established, verify the *dialplan* of the server to be sure that there are routes to get to every client.

Answer (score 1):

Snom phones are very feature-rich devices. They are capable of calling each other by IP address.

Try to enter IP address of one of them with the dialpad of the other one using * (asterisk sign) as a replacement for dot (like 192*168*0*1 for 192.168.0.1).

I've used that method for building a much bigger system. I've just uploaded a directory containing each phone's IP as well as its corresponded make via CVS-file import pn each phone and it worked.

As far as I remember (it was quite some time ago) you have to set a port of 5060 (which is standart SIP port) in some menu on the phone's web interface.